# jQuery .show/.hide gets triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with 4 tiles that display 2 options when a mouse hovers over it: **New Form** and **Form List**

However, I want these two options hidden unless the user is currently hovered over the tile. This is working fine but it does it 2 or 3 times after the first hover event. Basically, on page load, the 2 options are hidden and the tiles are displayed. Once I hover into the first tile, the two options then get displayed using the `.show()` method. If my mouse leaves the tile, the `.hide()` method is called hiding the two options.

However, if I hover my mouse back into the same tile, it executes both `.hide()` and `.show()` 2 times and sometimes even more than that. I'm assuming I'm doing something stupid but can't find any help on the web. JSFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/n97M8/

[image]

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container
            {
                height: 150px;
                text-align:center;
            }
            .FormTiles
            {
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                float:left;
                width: 150px;
                height: 0px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                background-color: green;
                color: white;
                display: inline; 
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size:small;
                margin-right: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 150px;
            }

            #optionsContainer, #optionsContainer1, #optionsContainer2, #optionsContainer3
            {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                bottom: 0;
                background-color: gray;
                padding-top: 3px;
                padding-bottom: 3px;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="FormTiles" id="workForInspector">Work For Inspector Form
                <div id="optionsContainer">
                    <div class="FormTilesNewForm">New Form</div>
                    <div class="FormTilesToList">Form List</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="FormTiles" id="Form2">Form 2
                <div id="optionsContainer1">
                    <div class="FormTilesNewForm">New Form</div>
                    <div class="FormTilesToList">Form List</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="FormTiles" id="Form3">Form 3
                <div id="optionsContainer2">
                    <div class="FormTilesNewForm">New Form</div>
                    <div class="FormTilesToList">Form List</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="FormTiles" id="Form4">Form 4
                <div id="optionsContainer3">
                    <div class="FormTilesNewForm">New Form</div>
                    <div class="FormTilesToList">Form List</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#workForInspector").hover(function () {
                    $("#optionsContainer").show("fast");
                });
                $("#workForInspector").mouseout(function () {
                    $("#optionsContainer").hide("fast");
                });

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.stop()` function to stop the queueing of mouse movements:

```
$("#workForInspector").hover(function () {
    $("#optionsContainer").stop().show("fast");
}, function () {
    $("#optionsContainer").stop().hide("fast");
});
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n97M8/1/)

Comment: Thank you! Turns out I just had it structured wrong. Changed my structure to match yours and it worked like a charm. Didn't need the `.stop()` either. Will mark as answer!